# Multi-feedback active bandpass filter - transfer function derivation

Tags: transfer-function, band-pass

new to this forum. I have a question about a certain topic I'm struggling with. I have this circuit, C1 and C2 are equal and therefore just described as C:

[image]

I want to deduce the transfer function Vout/Vin with the help of node voltage analysis. This is what I have as of now:

Equation 1: Vb = 0

Equation 2: (Va-Vin)/R1+Va/R2+(Va-Vb)/(1/(I*2*pifC))+(Va-Vout)/(1/(2*Pi*I)fC) = 0

I can't seem to get it to work. I define the equations in maple and solve them like a system, but I believe I must be writing the equations wrong. Can anybody give me a helping hand?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need the node B equation: \$\frac{0-V_a}{j \: 2\pi fC}+\frac{0-V_{out}}{R_3}=0\$

Answer (score 1):

You did not include R3 into your equations. Below you can find a solution using Mathematica. 
[image]

Comment: The capacitor C2 is equal to C1.

e3 := (vb-va)*(I*2)*Pi*f*C+(vb-vout)/R3 = 0

e2 := (va-vin)/r1+va/r2+(va-vb)*(2*Pi*f*C*I)+(-vout+va)*(2*Pi*f*C*I) = 0

e1 := (Vout-Vb)/R3-(Va-Vb)*(I*2)*Pi*f*C = 0

e4 := vb = 0

solve({e1, e2, e3, e4}, [va, vout])
holy shit formatting

Comment: The thing I don't understand in your picture is that you have two equations that are identical, eq1 and 3

Comment: I made an update.

Comment: Thanks dude! Not sure why, but it worked replacing 2Pi*f*I*C with s. Somehow maple didnt want to solve it in frequency.

Answer (score 0):

To perform this analysis using impedances in the frequency world, you will need to use complex algebra and make the capacitive impedances to be imaginary; that is the terms in you equations must have a "j" to indicate they are imaginary.  I don't know what maple is, but the voltages and currents will have a real and imaginary component.

Comment: The impedances of the capacitors are written as 1/(2Pi*I*f*C) where I is the imaginary unit, so basically the same. The impedance of the resistors is as they are just their value in ohms. Maple is a CAS program. By writing equations I should get x amount of equations with x amounts of unknowns and solve these. I just can't get the equations right.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this.  If your software handles complex numbers you are all set.  Just add (Vout-Vb)/R3 - (Va - Vb)/ (1/(I*2*pifC)) = 0.

Comment: As an electrical engineer who uses maple, I recommend solving this by hand. It will likely be faster and will benefit your understanding.

Comment: I'm just a student, but we have been teached to solve this in maple. I understand the technicalities but we just don't solve it by hand. Since you use maple, I was wondering if you could help me solve it in maple, cause it doesn't work atm. Guess I can't upload a picture of the maplesheet in the comments though.